# Quantstrat add.rule arguments: orderqty vs tradeSize vs maxSize

Tags: r, quantstrat

I can't find in the **Quantstrat** documentation the definition of the **add.rule** arguments. I'm interested in knowing what is the difference between **orderqty**, **tradeSize** and **maxSize**.

Found the following related material on [quantstrattrader](https://quantstrattrader.wordpress.com/2014/09/24/nuts-and-bolts-of-quantstrat-part-iv/):

The `orderqty` argument applies only when there’s no `osFUN` specified. It can take a flat value (E.G. 1, 2), or, when the rule type is “exit”, a quantity of “all”, to flatten a position.

The `osFUN` specifies the order-sizing function to use. The `osFUN` argument is actually a function object that gets passed in as an argument. If you do not wish to use an `osFUN`, simply use a flat quantity, such as 100, or if using exit type orders, use “all” to flatten a position.

This is how an `add.rule` function looks like:

```
 add.rule(strategy.st, name = "ruleSignal",
          arguments = list(sigcol = "longsig",
                           sigval = TRUE,               
                           ordertype = "market",
                           prefer = "Open",            
                           orderside = "long",
                           orderqty = 100,
                           replace = FALSE,            
                           osFUN = osMaxPos,
                           tradeSize = 100,
                           maxSize = 100),
          type = "enter")
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@blackknight316 is right.  Take a look at the code for `ruleSignal`  (print ruleSignal). You'll see no formal arguments exist for `tradeSize` or `maxSize`.

Yet the `ruleSignal` function doesn't generate an error when it is called because it uses the ellipses argument (which is `...`).  Read about this special parameter in the official R language documentation.

Print `ruleSignal` and take a look at the source.  This is one part:

```
orderqty <- osFUN(strategy = strategy, data = mktdata, 
                timestamp = timestamp, orderqty = orderqty, ordertype = ordertype, 
                orderside = orderside, portfolio = portfolio, 
                symbol = symbol, ... = ..., ruletype = ruletype, 
                orderprice = as.numeric(orderprice))
```

which uses `...` (as does `addOrder`).

`tradeSize` and `maxSize` are included in `add.rule` in the linked code probably because they are passed through to the ordersizing function used in the example you link.  See the argument `osFUN=osDollarATR` which is actually an object which is a function.  `osDollarATR` is of course user defined by the author.  You'll probably find the definition of that function in another blog post there and see `tradeSize` and `maxSize` are formal arguments to it.

Answer (score 3):

I just finished reading that blog and saw this question. I will answer my best!

According to [Guy Yollin](https://4310b1a9-a-a8fb2076-s-sites.googlegroups.com/a/r-programming.org/home/files/quantstratII.pdf?attachauth=ANoY7cr1SkgWuDlAlrAOqM4Q5qN52jGOsRNomViBJq3znFXwcTYnRP8ZwUlxovmpGkCdPvLX80bCNbav1cB_3k_vWlG82ZoX_YCPb8lxcudZD5k-0yAC5f9ocoGwRX2b1PYAfSvbYoWppdHebWbCnfMnG_5crn-F20XOzZkeZ4kAp7QxGcMhSm-IG6xBddLYVab2ZRl1Ouq0Kzo9g4jF6zM9qfC8_ZwyuQ%3D%3D&attredirects=0)'s notes. `orderqty` is the main argument. I dont see him using any other arguments in his rule.

Hope this answers your question.